# Is it possible to configure the file name of a RollingFileAppender to include date followed by process ID?

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I've currently got log4net configured to generate log file names like `THWS_Process1234_debug_20181102.log`, using the following configuration in the web.config file of my web application:

```
<appender name="DebugLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">      
  <file value="C:\Logs\THHWS_Process%processid_debug_.log"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} | %thread | %-5level | %logger | %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I have two types of logs, audit and debug.  When I have an issue to investigate I'd like the two relevant log files, for audit and debug, to have the same root file name so sorting by filename the two files appear next to one another.  So I'd like to generate log file names like:

```
THHWS_20181102_Process1234_audit.log
THHWS_20181102_Process1234_debug.log
THHWS_20181102_Process9876_audit.log
THHWS_20181102_Process9876_debug.log
```

I want to configure the file names in the web.config without resorting to code.  Is it possible to generate file names with the date before the process ID via the web.config file?

## What I've Tried

I've tried two approaches: Adding the process ID to the datePattern and using a pattern string in the filename.  The results:

### 1) Adding the process ID to the datePattern:

```
  ...     
  <file value="C:\Logs\THHWS_.log"/>
  ...
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd_Process%processid_debug"/>
  ...
```

This resulted in file names like `THHWS_20181102_Proce33proce33i2_2ebuA.D..log`, I assume because it sees "s" as representing "second", and "d" and "g" representing .NET datetime patterns.

So I then tried escaping those characters:

```
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd_Proce\s\s%proce\s\si\d_\debu\g"/>
```

This gets me closer: `THHWS_20181102_Processprocessid_debug.log`

Is there any way I can include the process ID after the date, however?

### 2) Using a pattern string in the filename:

```
<appender name="DebugLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">      
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Logs\THHWS_%date{yyyyMMdd}_Process%processid_debug.log"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  ...
</appender>
```

This resulted in the following filename: `THHWS_20181102_Process20220_debug.log.2018-11-02`

So I changed the rollingStyle to Size:

```
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
```

This results in the correct filename: `THHWS_20181102_Process22180_debug.log` However, it doesn't roll the filename when the date changes.